# Cel Shading in react three fiber?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

Trying to implement a cel shaded model in my project.
And found [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_variations_toon) in three js docs

The source code for the same is available [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_variations_toon.html).
However, I am confused as to how I can apply the imported OutlineEffect to the canvas I am returning.

```js
        <Canvas sRGB shadowMap camera={{ fov: 75 }}>
            <OutlineEffect ref = { renderer } />
            <ambientLight intensity={0.2} />
            <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
            <pointLight position={[-10, -10, -10]} intensity={0.5} />
... directional light ...
            <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <Logo position = {[0, 0, 0]} />
            </Suspense>
            <mesh rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} position={[0, -2.3, 0]} receiveShadow>
                <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[10, 10]} />
                <shadowMaterial attach="material" transparent opacity={0.5}/>
            </mesh>
        </Canvas>
```

The toon shader is implemented for the Logo object,

```js
        <mesh
            {...props}
            ref={group}
            castShadow
            dispose={null}
            geometry = {nodes.Curve001.geometry}
            scale = {active ? [46, 46, 46] : [42, 42, 42]}
            rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
            onClick = {(e) => setActive(!active)}
            onPointerOver = {(e) => setHover(true)}
            onPointerOut = {(e) => setHover(false)}
        >
            <meshToonMaterial
                color = {diffuseColor}
                gradientMap = { gradientMap }
            />
        </mesh>
```

The example uses a THREE.WebGlRenderer()
uses that to create an effect using OutlineEffect(renderer)
and then uses the effect to render the scene.

Comment: You could use post processing and OutlinePass. Or simply don't use react :)

Comment: @Marquizzo Funny, that that example was the first thing i mentioned in my post. The problem is that it applies the effect to the renderer and uses that renderer to render the scene. I am confused as to how I can do that in react-three-fiber

Comment: @Blaine My mistake, I guess I skipped ahead of that part on your question!